# Is there a way to see if a change occurred in a dual Listbox component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-duallistbox

I am using salesforce's dual list box aura component and controller.

Markup

```
<aura:attribute name="displayUserSettings" type="boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="displayUserSettingsWarning" type="boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="displayRevertMsg" type="boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.options}" action="{!c.valueChanged}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="selectedOptionList" type="List" />


    <aura:handler  name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                        { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
                                                        { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
                                                        { label: 'divish', value: 'es' },
                                                        { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
                                                        { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
                                                        { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' }]"/>





     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.displayUserSettings}">
        <!--<div aura:id="UserSettingsModal">-->
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
                aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" onclick="{! c.clickX}"
                            alternativeText="close" variant="bare-inverse" class="slds-modal__close" />
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">
                            {!$Label.c.MTX_User_Settings}
                        </h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <lightning:dualListbox name="languages" label="User Settings" sourceLabel="List View"
                            selectedLabel="Additional Details" fieldLevelHelp="This is a dual listbox"
                            options="{!v.options}" onchange="{! c.handleChange }" />
                    </div>

                    <!--
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                            onclick="{!c.doRevert}">{!$Label.c.MTX_Revert_to_Default}
                        </button>

                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.save }">Save
                        </button>

                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.hideSettings}">Cancel
                        </button>
                    </footer> -->
                    <lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
                                              onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                                              ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}" />
                      <lightning:button label="{!$Label.c.MTX_Revert_to_Default}" onclick="{!c.doRevert}" />

                    <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.makeUnsavedChanges}" />
                    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.clearUnsavedChanges}"/>


                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        <!--</div>-->
    </aura:if>
```

JS

```
makeUnsavedChanges: function(component, event, helper) {
         var unsaved = component.find("unsaved");
         unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true, { label: 'Settings' });
     },
     clearUnsavedChanges: function(component, event, helper) {
         var unsaved = component.find("unsaved");
         unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(false);
     },
     handleSave: function(component, event, helper) {
         //... my custom save logic
         // When the custom save logic has completed the setUnsavedChanges method
         // must be called again to return control to the lightning UI
         var unsaved = component.find("unsaved");
         //if (something went wrong) {
           // return control to the lightning UI while indicating that the content is still unsaved, preventing it from being dismissed
          // unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true);

         //else {
           // return control to the lightning UI while indicating that the content is saved
           unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(false);

     },
})
```

I incorporated the lightning:unsavedChanges, but I still don't reveive my alert after I try to exit out of my modal. Can lightning:unsavedChanges be used for dual listbox?

Answer (score 1):

One solution (in case anyone runs into this) is to create a boolean attribute
   `<aura:attribute name="listChanged" type="Boolean" default="false" />`
And in the .js add

```
        component.set("v.listChanged", true);
```

Set the attribute to true or false where needed. For instance in my doCancel method, if my list hasn't changed, I can close the tab

```
doCancel: function (component, event, helper) {
        if (component.get("v.listChanged") == false) {
            helper.closeTab(component);
        }
        else {
            component.set("v.displayUserSettings", component.get("v.displayUserSettings"));
            helper.showHideDisplayUserSettings(component);
            helper.showHideUnsavedWaringOverlay(component);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a separate `previousValues` aura attribute that you maintain as the changes happen (i.e. only set `previousValues` at the end of your `handleChange` method), so you can reference against them.

Also, try `event.getParam("oldValue")` to see if it gives you the old values (this works on the `change` aura:handler but not sure if it works here)

Comment: Can you help the OP by providing samples of what you are suggesting?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I found this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueChange/documentation, So it helps access the old value, I was just trying to identify if there has been a change and IF theres a change I would display a warning if the user tries to close this modal without saving the change.

Comment: @DejaBond In [Spring 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_lc_unsaved_changes.htm) they introduced [`lightning:unsavedChanges`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) - start there and see if you can use it to pop up that warning message

Comment: You can see a full example of `lightning:unsavedChanges` [here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2019/01/unsaved-changes-in-spring-19.html)

Comment: I am using lightning:unsavedChanges, but I am still not getting the notification, am I incorporating it wrong? @BrianMiller